# Excel Pivot Table - Field Calculation using Count feature

Tags: excel, pivot

[image]

From Pivot Table, i wish to divide "Count of All Part" / "Count of Bad Part"
In Field Calculation, How should i do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, I hope this helps:

1. Click on the pivot table and Click on "PivotTable Analyze" tab in the ribbon.
2. From "Calculations" group, click on "Fields, Items, & Sets"
3. Choose "Calculated Field"
4. In the dialog box, provide your desired column name.
5. Then in the Formula field, there should already be an equal sign. Click after equal sign and from the field list below, click on "Bad Part" then click on "Insert Field" button.
6. Type / (division sign) from keyboard.
7. Click on "All Part" and click on "Insert Field"
8. Click on OK

That should show the result you want.